Error in switching to postgres from h2 in WSO2 Identity Server

I have followed https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/configure/databases/carbon-database/change-to-postgresql/ and updated the "deployment.toml" file with postgres credentials.

Uploaded postgresql-42.7.3.jar in repository\components\lib

When I run the server (bin/wso2server.sh)  I get the following error... please advise


ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" versions)
Cannot start User Manager Core bundle org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" versions)
Need to run the WS02 server which uses Postgres as datastore and not defautl H2
INSTALLATION LOG
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\CODE\RnD\wso2is-7.0.0
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,201] []  INFO {org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.support.EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Sending Event Admin notification (configuration successful) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,408] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Operating System : Windows 11 10.0, amd64
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Version     : 17.0.11
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.11+7-LTS-207,Oracle Corporation
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Carbon Home      : C:\CODE\RnD\wso2is-7.0.0
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,411] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Temp Dir    : C:\CODE\RnD\wso2is-7.0.0\tmp
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,412] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - User             : Rochak, en-IN, Asia/Calcutta
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,419] [] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator.start() of bundle org.wso2.carbon.core.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.core_4.10.9
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator.start(CarbonCoreActivator.java:79)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
... 14 more
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,547] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} - Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,661] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.verification.provider.internal.IdVProviderMgtServiceComponent} - IdVProviderMgtService bundle activated successfully.
[2024-05-11 12:17:15,790] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.hash.provider.pbkdf2.internal.PBKDF2HashServiceComponent} - PBKDF2 bundle activated successfully.
[2024-05-11 12:17:16,544] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.onboard.core.service.internal.ServiceComponent} - User onboard api core service component activated successfully.
[2024-05-11 12:17:16,633] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Office365SupportMexComponent} - Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
[2024-05-11 12:17:16,643] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} - DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
[2024-05-11 12:17:18,612] []  INFO {org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner} - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2024-05-11 12:17:21,104] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:402)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:80)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:948)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10114)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:347)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:277)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:155)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" versions)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:767)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:134)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1067)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:928)
... 35 more
[2024-05-11 12:17:21,128] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} - Cannot start User Manager Core bundle org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:80)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:323)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:402)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:948)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10114)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:347)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:277)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:155)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" versions)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:767)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:134)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1067)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:928)
... 35 more

What is the JDK version you're running?
